# Web page falling when we install the SSL

Tags: ssl, apache2

We want to install SSL certificate to a website (we have installed the SSL to several pages without any problem, but this time we are having problems).

When we activate the certificate in apache Vhost, the page stays in blank.

The server web is Apache2, his data :

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Jan 31 2014 18:55:37
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

The S.O: is **Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)**.

The apache vhost for this domain:

```
/*****************Apache2 Vhost MyDomain.com*****************************/
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin sistems@mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.MyDomain.com MyDomain.com

    Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

    SuexecUserGroup www.MyDomain.com MyDomain.com

    <Directory /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/ftp/htdocs>
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/conf/fcgid .php
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
                SetHandler fcgid-script
        </FilesMatch>
        Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/ftp/htdocs
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/logs/access.log combined


SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/SSLCertificat.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/Intermediate.crt

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/ftp/cgi-bin/

    <Directory /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/ftp/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Options ExecCGI -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /awstats-icon/ /usr/share/awstats/icon/
    ScriptAlias /awstats/ /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Options ExecCGI -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /awstats-icon/ /usr/share/awstats/icon/
    ScriptAlias /awstats/ /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /var/www/virtual/MyDomain.com/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Options ExecCGI -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_bw.c>
        BandwidthModule On
        ForceBandWidthModule On
        Bandwidth all 204800
        MaxConnection all 50
    </Ifmodule>
</VirtualHost>

/*************************************************************************/
```

The ports.conf:

```
/**************************************************************************/
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    #XXX.XXX.XXX is the server Ip.
    Listen 443
    Listen XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
    Listen XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
</IfModule>
/**************************************************************************/
```

And this is the apache2.conf:

```
    /**************************************************************************/
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          100
    ServerLimit         100
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
    /**************************************************************************/
```

In the logs we have this error (although we do not believe that is the cause of the fall of page):

> [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `MyServerName' does NOT
>   match server name!?

Please anyone can help us with the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved following this manual (without changing the port):

http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/ubuntu/https_ssl_custom_port

Basically I created another Vhost for SSL version of my site ,and I added this block before :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean your SSL certificate as been self signed, so it can't be validated as a securized SSL. So you need to buy one.

Each domain & subdomain has to be registered in you SSL certificate* Each domain & subdomain has to be registered in you SSL certificate :

- If you paid for the SSL certificate, you should check if it is a WildCard SSL which allow all subdomain to be a valid SSL domain.
- Else you can test your certificate to see for which domain it applies with the command:

  ```
  openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/ssl/Intermediate.crt -noout -text | grep -A1 "Subject Alternative"
  ```

the result of this command, will show you all which domain your certificate can be apllied

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
We have acquired the certificate for this domain (mydomain.com), and the command returns the result:

 **X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
             DNS:www.mydomain.com, DNS:otherdomain.com,**.

So in vhost we tried both ways: ServerName with and without  www, but still does not work. Another idea? The ports.conf file is correct?

Comment: Can you post the log information of access & error when you try to load the website in https with a browser ?